# How do I use different prefixes when renaming multiple files in Java?

Tags: java, pdf, directory, prefix, file-rename

I am trying to create a Java app (with swing) which renames pdf files with a set naming convention. Currently the files are named:

```
1.pdf, 2.pdf...... 10.pdf, 11.pdf...... 20.pdf, 21.pdf etc.
```

So I decide to add a prefix `(ABC_0)` to the file name. The new file names should be:

```
ABC_01.pdf, ABC_02.pdf.... ABC_10.pdf, ABC_11.pdf...... ABC_20.pdf, ABC_21.pdf etc.
```

So far everything is working well. The only problem I am facing is that when the prefix gets added to a pdf file name with a number 10 and above, it's renamed as:

```
ABC_010.pdf, ABC_011.pdf...... ABC_020.pdf, ABC_021.pdf etc.
```

This is wrong. The `0` should only be added to the pdf file names with a number 1–9 in it.

Could you please help me?

This is the code that I need help with.

```
        {
            String dir= txt_src.getText();
            String addPrefix= "ABC_0";
            File dirFile,dirFile1;
            File oldfile, newfile;
            String newname;
            String filenames[];
            int i, count;
            dirFile = new File(dir);
            if (!dirFile.exists() || !dirFile.isDirectory()) 
            {
                message("File not exist or not a directory");
            }
            filenames = dirFile.list();
            for(i = count = 0; i < filenames.length; i++) 
            {
                if (filenames[i].equals(".")) continue; 
                if (filenames[i].equals("..")) continue;
                dirFile1 = new File(dir+"\\"+filenames[i]); 
                if (!dirFile1.isDirectory())
                {oldfile = new File(dirFile, filenames[i]); 
                    newname = addPrefix + filenames[i]; 
                    newfile = new File(dirFile, newname); 
                    message("Files Renamed Successfully");
                    if (oldfile.renameTo(newfile)) count++; 
                    else 
                    {
                        message("Unable to rename " + oldfile);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make sure that your filenames are padded with zeros like this:

```
public String pad(String fileName, int len) {
  if (fileName.length() >= len) {
    return fileName;
  }
  String padded = "0000000" + fileName;  // Change the number of zeros to your needs
  return  padded.substring(padded.length() - len); 
}
```

Then you just have to prepend "ABC_" to the padded value:

```
String newName = "ABC_" + pad(oldNmame, 6); // produce 6 characters per String
```

produces results like:

```
10.pdf gets ABC_10.pdf
1.pdf gets ABC_01.pdf
a.pdf gets ABC_0a.pdf
100.pdf gets ABC_100.pdf
a.a gets ABC_000a.a
```

Comment: hey thank you so much, i tried this code out and it worked perfectly. i just wanted to ask you, how does this work, and what is the "6" for?

Comment: @user3566271 the 6 is simply the minimum length of the string created by the pad function. If the fileName is already long enough, I return it unchanged. If not, I prepend enough 0s and then return the last 6 characters. So if you would have 1000.pdf, just use 8 instead and everything has the same length.

Answer (score 0):

remove 0 from addPrefix

```
String addPrefix= "ABC_0";
```

use  this

```
String addPrefix= "ABC_";
```

updated this line

```
 newname = addPrefix+i + filenames[i];
```

Comment: Hey, thanks so much, but that didn't work, it still gives me a "0" before the 2 digit number.

Comment: @user3566271 It should work , in which case 2 digit number it giving you '0'

Answer (score 0):

I would just create 2 different String variables and let it choose. Check if the number is less than 10, if it is, have it use the string with the 0 `ABC_0`

If it's greater than 10, use the string without the 0 `ABC_`

Comment: that what i planned to do, but i don't know how to. if you could please help me out with the code of how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Check my little program. It reads the number before the extension ".pdf". If the number has a length of 1, add a 0 before adding a prefix.

```
String pdfNames[] = new String[] { "2.pdf", "6.pdf", "19.pdf", "26.pdf" };
String newNames[] = new String[pdfNames.length];
String prefix = "ABC_";
for (int i = 0; i < pdfNames.length; i++) {
    String name = pdfNames[i].split(".pdf")[0];
    System.out.println(name);

    newNames[i] = prefix;

    if (name.length() == 1)
        newNames[i] += "0";

    newNames[i] += name;
    System.out.println(newNames[i]);
}
```

But think about the case you have with files named like 123, 1234 and so on. Then you have to add more than one 0.

**EDIT**

In your code

```
filenames = dirFile.list();
for(i = count = 0; i < filenames.length; i++) 
{
    ...
```

you first fill your `String` array `filenames` with a list of file names ;-)

In the for loop you can get the length of the filename by `filenames[i].split(".pdf")[0].length()`.

Comment: hey thank you, i did try this, the problem that i have is that, i cannot get the length of the file name as i do with a string, and also i don't know how to convert a filename to a string, i dont even know if its possible.